# How to solve this geometric+arithmetic recurrence

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations, closed-form

I've been stuck on this recurrence closed form question for a while now:

$S(n)=9S(n-1)+4n, n > 1$

$S(1) = 4$

After expanding a couple iterations to find a pattern, I came up with this:

$4*9^{n-1}+4*(n*\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}9^k-\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}k*9^k)$

$=4*9^{n-1}+4*(n*\frac{9^{n-1}-1}{9-1}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}k*9^k)$

However, I can't seem to get further than than that in simplifying it in terms of n.
Can anyone point me in the right direction or show me how best to simplify this recurrence?

Comment: I don't know if your formula is correct, but $\sum_{k=0}^{n} a^k = \frac{a^{n+1} - 1}{a-1}$ is well known.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed I forgot to simplify that part, however, the trickiest section I'm having trouble with is the second summation of products term.

Comment: You can differentiate the sum I gave term by term. What do you get?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by differentiating it term by term?

Comment: It is a sum and you can thus differentiate every term by the sum on its own.

Answer (score 1):

The observed pattern is fine. We have
\begin{align*}
S(n)&=4\cdot 9^{n-1}+4\left(n\frac{9^{n-1}-1}{9-1}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}k\,9^k\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}9^{n-1}\left(n+8\right)-\frac{1}{2}n-4\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}k\,9^{k}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
In (1) we have collected terms and we start the index $k$ with $1$, since the term with $k=0$ is zero. In order to get a closed form of $\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}k\,9^{k}$ by elementary means we can use the trick to write  $k=\sum_{j=1}^k 1$ and then rearrange the sums to obtain geometric sums which admit a closed form.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}k\,9^k}&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}\left(\sum_{j=1}^k1\right)9^k=\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}\sum_{j=1}^k9^k\\
> &=\sum_{1\leq j\leq k\leq n-2}9^k=\sum_{j=1}^{n-2}\sum_{k=j}^{n-2}9^k\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{j=1}^{n-2}\frac{9^{n-1}-9^j}{9-1}\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{1}{8}9^{n-1}\sum_{j=1}^{n-2}1-\frac{1}{8}\sum_{j=1}^{n-2}9^j\tag{4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{64}9^{n-1}(8n-17)+\frac{9}{64}}\tag{5}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we write the index region conveniently to better see how we to rearrange the sums.
- In (3) we apply the geometric summation formula to the inner sum.
- In (4) we split the sum and factor out terms.
- In (5) we apply the geometric summation formula again.

> Combining (1)  and (5) we obtain for $n\geq 1$:
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{S(n)}&=\frac{1}{2}9^{n-1}\left(n+8\right)-\frac{1}{2}n-\frac{1}{16}9^{n-1}(8n-17)-\frac{9}{16}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{16}\left(9^{n+1}-8n-9\right)}
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

$$S_n=9S_{n-1}+4 n$$ Let $S_n=T_n+k n$ and replace
$$T_n+k n=9T_{n-1}+9k(n-1)+4n$$ I f we want to get rid of the $n$
$$kn=9k(n-1)+4n \implies k=-\frac 12$$ Now, the problem is simple.

Comment: How did you removed the $T_n$ and $9T_{n-1}$ ?

Comment: @KennyCheng. I did not remove anything. I just want to get rid of the $n$; so the trick. Now, you are left with a simple equation in $T_n$.